# How to change values of variables using methods?

Tags: variables, instance

I am having troubles incrementing the value of my instance variables. I tried making a method so that for every pet I buy, it will add that much to how many I already have. But when I print dogs variable, it says 0 even though I added 2. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

public class myStuff
    static int dogs;
    static int cats;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myStuff.buy(dogs, 2);
    System.out.println(dogs);

}
public static void buy(int pet, int howMany) {
    pet = pet + howMany;
}
```

}

Comment: Why your first parameter is an integer ?

Comment: because my dogs and cats variables are integer

Comment: So you can start using OOP and create a class 'Animal' for example which can contain a `String` describing the type of Animal and an `int` 'howMany'.

Answer (score 0):

you cant do that in java, since it is [pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, method parameters are passed by value (which means the value of `dogs`in your case is passed in the first Place, but never touched). Objects however, are manipulated by reference. So, if you want to increase the number of pets, you could use a class `Pet` with a value `count`

```
public class Pet {
    private int count;

    public Pet(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

If you then pass an instance of `Pet` to your `buy` function and increase the count via `setCount`, the value will be saved.